# Custom horizontal scroolbar - HOW?

Tags: html, css

I try create custom scroolbar horizontal in div.
I would get this effect:
[image]

And my try:
[image]

I used ::-webkit-scrollbar etc. but I do not know how to make the large button.

**My question:**

how to make a scrollbar like the picture number 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could figure this out is by faking a thickness difference. It doesn't seem to be possible to specifically make the handle wider or taller than the track. But you can use colors and transparencies to fake the effect.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: black;
}
div {
  margin: 40px auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
span{
  width: 1000px;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
}
div::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 10px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
div::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.scrollmenu {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
div.scrollmenu a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
div.scrollmenu a:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}
div.TV{
width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollmenu">
  <a href="#home">
    <div class="TV">Home</div>
  </a>

  <a href="#home">
    <div class="TV">Home</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#home">
    <div class="TV">Home</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#home">
    <div class="TV">Home</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#home">
    <div class="TV">Home</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#home">
    <div class="TV">Home</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#home">
    <div class="TV">Home</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#home">
    <div class="TV">Home</div>
  </a>


</div>
```